# Loading message appears at top instead of middle

Tags: html

I want to show loading message using ajax while page is loading. I had code but message is displayed at the top.. I want it to be in middle of screen..
What should i do ? Code snippet is as:

```
 <div id='loadpage'>
      <table height=100% width=100% border=0>
           <tr height=100%>
                <td width=100% align=center valign=center>Please Wait</td>
           </tr>
      </table>
 </div>
 var progressTimeID = setTimeout("document.getElementById('loadpage').innerHTML='<table style=\"height:100%;\" width=100% border=0><tr height=100%>    <td width=100% align=center valign=center>Please Wait</td></tr></table>';", 1000);
clearTimeout(progressTimeID);
```

thnx in advance

Comment: Create a jsFiddle for it and I may be able to help! valign in general gives me headaches and I'd suggest  you stay away from table based layouts in this day and age.

Comment: I have edited my answer so that it fits your needs, try it...

Answer (score 0):

I am sure it is because of your `height=100%` 100% of nothing is nothing. So make sure that all parents have a defined height. Even your body.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `html`, `body` and `div#loadpage` to `height:100%` in your CSS.

```css
html,
body,
div#loadpage
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

**EDIT:**

```
<html>
<head>

<script>

    function load_show() {

        document.getElementById('loadpage').innerHTML = "<img src=\"http://websurvey.textalk.se/en/pics/ajax-loader-big.gif\" />";

    }

    function show_div() {

        var progressTimeID = setTimeout(function(){load_show()}, 1000);

    }

</script>

<style>

    body {

        background: #fff;

    }

    #loadpage {

        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -33px;
        margin-left: -33px;
        width: 66px;
        height: 66px;

    }

    #click {

        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -50px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;

    }

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="click" onclick="show_div()">
    show loader
</div>

<div id="loadpage">
    CONTENT
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

- don't use table layout please.
- you can't clear timeout just after you start it. It will brake it so that it doesn't execute...

Comment: this is working in ALL browsers... I don't know for IE6 for sure but I think that it works there also. And I am not by any mean going to support table based design.